# Can you tell me how to find out where form info goes?

Tags: forms, submit, form-submit, newsletter

Thank you for taking a look at my post.  I have this newsletter form and it appears to be working fine, but I don't know where the information goes!

```
<form id="subscribe-form" name="sibscribe" method="post">
    <label>
        <input class="subscribetext" type="text" onFocus="if(this.value =='Enter E-mail:' ) this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter E-mail:'" value="Enter E-mail:" name="keyword" />
    </label>
    <a onClick="document.getElementById('subscribe-form').submit()" class="button" href="Thank You.html">subscribe</a>
</form>
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

The best way to figure out for you is to go to Firebug Net bug while the page/form submits and inspect the tabs like:

**Params| Headers|Responses|XML|Cookies**